# Better filtering for table in meteor

Tags: javascript, optimization, meteor

I have a table I am trying to add filtering for in meteor by certain fields and tags. Right now there is a field for each row called `race` and `against`. There are two select elements above the table (`race-select` and `against-select`) you can use to filter out which results on the table you want to see but the code is really clunky and if I want to add more filtering for other tags the code is just going to get messier.

Some of the code is just trying to deal with the initial values of the Session.

```
var racelist = ['zerg', 'terran', 'protoss'];

Template.buildsList.helpers({
  builds : function() {
    if (typeof(Session.get('race-select')) == 'undefined' || Session.get('race-select') == 'all races'){
      Session.set('race-select', racelist);
    }
    if (typeof(Session.get('against-select')) == 'undefined' || Session.get('against-select') == 'all races'){
      Session.set('against-select', racelist);
    }
    return Builds.find({race : {$in : Session.get("race-select")}, against : {$in : Session.get("against-select")}}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  }
});

Template.buildsList.events({
  "change #race-select" : function(e){
    Session.set('race-select', [$(e.target).val().toLowerCase()])
  },
  "change #against-select" : function(e) {
    Session.set('against-select', [$(e.target).val().toLowerCase()])
  }
})
```

There is a lot of nearly repeated lines but I want to know if there is a better way of implementing this sort of filtering feature.

Comment: I highly recommend to use Filter-Collections package for any kind of filtering in meteor. You can clone it from https://github.com/parhelium/filter-collections, there are few bugfixes.  After you clone simply add to packages dir to make accessible immediatelly in you meteor app and type meteor add parhelium:filter-collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package I already checked out just added support for custom filters in the past couple days. https://atmospherejs.com/aslagle/reactive-table . You can have multiple custom filters tied to one table and its much simpler to use.

The code ended up looking something like this :

```
Template.raceFilter.created = function() {
    this.filter = new ReactiveTable.Filter('race-filter', ['race']);
};

Template.raceFilter.events({
    "change" : function(event, template) {
        var input = $(event.target).val().toLowerCase();
        if(input != 'all races'){
            template.filter.set(input);
        }else {
            template.filter.set("");
        }
    }
});
```

The `raceFilter` template can be any sort of input, (select, text box, radio).